# how to handle the state of the whole app when using the app or getting out from it

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

how could I know if the app is on the screen or not , I mean how could I know if the user is using the app right now or not so if he is using it something should happen if minimize it or stop it something should happen , so is there any way to do this in  Android Studio .

Answer (score 0):

You can know if your app in screen or not (if UI is hidden or showing) using this Method:

```
override fun onTrimMemory(level: Int) {
        if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
            Log.d("TAG", "HiddenUI")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an application class life cycle method to achieve this